# Function Composition in Scala

Tags: scala

I am trying to write a function that takes two functions and composes them. I tried the solution below and a few other variants but not much success.

```
def compose1[A, B, C](f: A => B, g: B => C)(x: A) = f(g(x))
```

The error I get is

```
<console>:21: error: type mismatch;
 found   : x.type (with underlying type A)
 required: B
       def compose1[A, B, C](f: A => B, g: B => C)(x: A) = f(g(x))
                                                               ^
```

Full disclosure this is part of a university exercise designed to teach us Scala although it's not for credit. The question is really poorly phrased (it was literally the function declaration and the sentence I used above) and there was no examples or explanation given before hand, I think I don't have a good enough understanding of Scala to even understand the question. Would greatly appreciate some elaboration on the problem, thanks for help!

Comment: You may want to include some more details of the error you encountered.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look closely at the types: you are trying to feed `x` (type `A`) to the function `g` (which takes a `B` and returns a `C`). I'm sure you can pick it up from here.

Comment: @stmfunk and feel free to mark the answer as correct if you so feel. ;-)

Comment: no problem just need to wait a few minutes for it to let me